# return all possible outputs from a function then use it in another function

Tags: python, class

The purpose of this code is to read a directory which includes 5 files, then print these files names,But when I tried to do that I got weird result.

ps [This is experience not real code and meant to return all possible outputs from a function then use it in another function to do something with it within the same class]

Here is the code:

```
import os


class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dir = r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\script\New folder"

    def files(self):
        os.chdir(self.dir)
        for files in os.listdir(self.dir):
            return files

    def df(self):
        files = self.files()
        for file in files:
            print(file)
```

Here is what I expected:

file (1).txt

file (2).txt

file (3).txt

file (4).txt

file (5).txt

Here is the output:

f

i

l

e

(

1

)

.

t

x

t

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, what output do you want it to return? Give an example

Comment: You may want to read up on the `yield` keyword, it gives behavior similar to what you seem to be trying here.

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need the `os.chdir()` - and actually you definitly DONT want to do this as it can break other code's expectations about the current working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns a list of the files so you don't need to iterate over it. Change your `files` function to this:

```
def files(self):
    os.chdir(self.dir)
    files = os.listdir(self.dir)
    return files
```

Comment: You should have removed the `os.chdir()` part - it's useless and potentially harmful.

Answer (score 0):

Your first return() leads to the loop break, hence saving only 1 filename instead of all of them. Then, since str() is an iterable type, for() loop loops through it in an absolute correct way.

I suggest you'd want to do the following:

```
def files(self):
    output = []
    os.chdir(self.dir)
    for files in os.listdir(self.dir):
        output.append(files)
    return output
```

You might want to read more on [Iterables and Iterators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator).

Comment: Nothing at all. It was original poster's approach to iterate through it, so he might have a reason to do so.

Comment: If you're in doubt about the OP's intent, ask for precisions in a comment. A bad answer is worse than no answer (remember that answers are read by a lot of people who don't necessarily know better so let's not post bad code).